# PHP Array Comparison using If

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I am having a hard time trying to understand why I can't compare the values of two arrays in PHP. If I echo both of these during the loop using "echo $description->ItemDesriptionName;" and "echo $item->ItemName;" the values seem to show as the same, but when I try to compare them using if, nothing works. What am I missing?

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$categories = $xml->Menu->Categories;
$items = $xml->Menu->Categories->Items->ItemObject;
$itemdescription = $xml->Menu->Options->Description->DescriptionObject;

foreach($items as $item) {

    echo $item->ItemName . ' - ' . $item->Price . '</br>';

        foreach ($itemdescription as $description) {

            if ($description->ItemDescriptionName == $item->ItemName) {
                echo 'We have a match!';
                //where I would echo $description->ItemDescription;
            }
        } 
}

?>
```

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Menu>
        <Categories>
            <Name>Category 1</Name>
            <Items>
                <ItemObject>
                    <ItemName>Item 1</ItemName>
                    <Price>1</Price>
                </ItemObject>
                <ItemObject>
                    <ItemName>Item 2</ItemName>
                    <Price>3</Price>
                </ItemObject>               
            </Items>
        </Categories>
        <Options>
            <Description>
                <DescriptionObject>
                    <ItemDescriptionName>Item 1</ItemDescriptionName>
                    <ItemDescription>A Great item</ItemDescription>
                </DescriptionObject>
                <DescriptionObject>
                    <ItemDescriptionName>Item 2</ItemDescriptionName>
                    <ItemDescription>A Great item as well</ItemDescription>
                </DescriptionObject>                
            </Description>
        </Options>
    </Menu>
</Root>
```

Comment: Your IF has a typo here, does it also have a typo in your source? Description on the ItemDescriptionName property is missing an 'n'

Comment: The source didn't but it still does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare as string
and you have typo in ItemDescriptioName (ItemDescriptio**n**Name)

```
if ( (string)$description->ItemDescriptionName == (string)$item->ItemName) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string and then compare

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$menu  = $xml->Menu;
$categories = $xml->Menu->Categories;
$items = $xml->Menu->Categories->Items->ItemObject;
$itemdescription = $xml->Menu->Options->Description->DescriptionObject;
foreach($items as $item) {


         $itemname = $item->ItemName;
        foreach ($itemdescription as $description) {
            $descriptionname = $description->ItemDescriptionName ;
            echo $itemname."   ---- ".$descriptionname."<br/>";

            if((string)$itemname === (string)$descriptionname){
                echo "Yes its matched";
            }
        } 
}

?>
```

Working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The properties like `$description->ItemDescriptionName` are `SimpleXMLElement` objects. So you do not compare strings but two objects.

`SimpleXMLElement` objects implement the magic method `__toString()`. They can be cast to string automatically, but a compare between to objects will not trigger that. You can force it:

```
if ((string)$description->ItemDescriptionName === (string)$item->ItemName) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you access them directly instead using an accordant index?

...

```
$items = $xml->Menu->Categories->Items->ItemObject;
$itemdescription = $xml->Menu->Options->Description;

$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo $i.' '.$item->ItemName . ' - ' . $item->Price;
  echo $itemdescription->DescriptionObject[$i]->ItemDescriptionName[0];
  echo ' ';
  echo $itemdescription->DescriptionObject[$i]->ItemDescription[0];
  echo '</br>';
  $i++;
}
```